# StringFormat with value zero

Tags: wpf, xaml, textblock, string-formatting, componentart

I'm developing a wpf application with [componentart](http://www.componentart.com) I have a textblock like this

```
<TextBlock FontSize="28" Text="{Binding DataPoint.Y, StringFormat=\{0:#\\%\}}" Foreground="Black">
```

As you can see, my StringFormat puts a '%' sign after the number, but if my data is 0.0 (I fill the component in code behind, my variable is a double) I get "%", but I want to get "0%", how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use different `StringFormat`. Instead of `0:#` put `0:0`:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="28" Text="{Binding Path=MyDouble, StringFormat=\{0:0\\%\}}" Foreground="Black"/>
```

quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx):

> **#**: Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.
>
> **0**: Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.