# How to add symbol after number in listview datagrid column in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, string-formatting

Can someone help me with string formatting problem. I need to show data in listview and one column must contain percents but i only have number. How do I add % symbol after that number in listview datagrid column.

I don't know how to correctly format string using StringFormat.
Also, can someone direct me to some tutorials about string formatting.

Thanks

Comment: for example like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594523/stringformat-with-value-zero/17594950#17594950

Comment: Do you mean String.Format() or is this a property in the grid?

Comment: It'c a grid property in XAML. DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Discount, StringFormat='%'}"

Answer (score 0):

In your XAML for the column you want there to be a %, this should work:

`Binding="{Binding PercentNumber, StringFormat={}{0}%}"`