# Hide zero values with StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, string-formatting

I made a similar question [months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594523/stringformat-with-value-zero)

In this case I have a textblock like this

```
<TextBlock FontSize="28" Text="{Binding DataPoint.Y, StringFormat=\{0:0\\%\}}" Foreground="Black">
```

As you can see, my StringFormat puts a '%' sign after the number, if my data is 0.0 (I fill the component in code behind, my variable is a double) I get "0%"

But now I want to get "" if my text is 0.0

So far I have this:

```
 Text="{Binding DataPoint.Y, StringFormat=\{0:#.#\\%\}}"
```

But this retrieves "%", how can I get ""?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me

```
{0:#\\%;0:#;#}
```

Answer (score 5):

None of these worked for simple positive integers. I had a field which would always default to 0. To hide it, but not add any decimals places, I use:

```
Text="{Binding BuyerNumber, StringFormat=0;;#}"
```

Hope this helps someone out who is looking for integers only.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx). Specifically, see the ";" Section Separator.

Using `{0:#.#\\%;-#.#\\%;}` will give you the desired output, I believe.